# Thales Style Level Sets

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Encouraged by Joseph O'Rourke ( and inspired by the discussion at
 [Thales' semicircle theorem in higher dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/201281/6094) ), I ask about level sets in three
dimensional space occuring from considering how big an object looks
from different points.

As mentioned in the post above, Thales shows that for a line segment to
appear to subtend a given planar angle q, a two-dimensional eye has to
be at some point on a circular arc in order to see the segment appear that
large.  Joseph was hoping for something similar in three or higher
dimensions, involving a hemisphere as a possible locus for an
observer to view a disk and have that disk occupy the same solid
angle (appear to have the same area, if not the same shape),
regardless of the viewer's position on the hemisphere.

So I ask, for two test regions, the same question: where must an
observer place their eye to view a region R so that the solid angle
subtended by R is a given value q?  In Joseph's example, q was
$(2 - \sqrt{2})\pi$ steradians, and R was the base of a hemisphere
with the observer at its apex looking down.  My two test regions are
Joseph's disk, and a region which is two congruent rectangles separated
by a small distance.  You can substitute a block letter capital H instead,
with an arbitrarily thin cross member.  Also, pick your q greater than 0
and fix it before you start computing the locus.

For the disk, I imagine the locus will be a circular ellipsoid minus an
equatorial circle.  I currently reserve my guess on the locus for the
other region.

Comment: I like your ellipsoid conjecture for the disk, although perhaps it will only be "ellipsoid-like."

Comment: @Joseph, I suspect for the disk it will be a surface of revolution based on a curve simply derived from the graph that Douglas Zare provided to your question.  I conjecture ellipsoid just to give people something to refute, even though it is a natural first guess.  For a rectangular region, one could imagine a parameterized surface which sliced in one direction resembles circular arcs of measure alpha and sliced in an orthogonal direction has measure beta; I expect reality will be more complicated.  In order to draw out the subtleties, I proposed an H region instead.

Comment: Except the original motivation, is it that important to restrict the question to plane 2-dimensional figures ? (Actually the only sets for which I can answer the question are balls !)

Comment: At some point an anologous problem observing 3d objects in 3d space can be considered, but then the steradial projection may vary for other reasons, complicating the analysis.  There are enough subtleties in this version that I think it important to consider the vision problem in this special form.

Comment: I can write down an explicit formula in finite time for plane polygons, but it will be ugly...